# ADB2C Custom Policies and development environments

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

Is there an elegant way to use a single set of ADB2C IEF custom policies across multiple environments (eg dev/test/prod)?

This issue has arisen as we have designed two custom IEF policies - one for signin, and separately one for signup

On the signin page ADB2C tries to generate a url for signup, but because we have a custom policy for signup we need to rewrite this URL in javascript so that it points to a different url
(as described in these q/a's) :

[B2C - How to override sign up now link (custom policy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309366/b2c-how-to-override-sign-up-now-link-custom-policy)

[Msal 2.0 - how to generate Sign Up link with Azure B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63022620/msal-2-0-how-to-generate-sign-up-link-with-azure-b2c)

But now we start hitting more issues. We can't rewrite the url to **myapp.com/signup**, because we need to rewrite it based on the environment. It needs to rewrite to **dev-app.com/signup** or **test-app.com/signup** etc

So the only way I can see to fix this is to use separate `ContentDefinitions` for each environment, each with customised javascript.

But then I also need individual policies for each environment so that each policy can use a specific content definition file!

Ugh.  Is there an easier way than trying to maintain what should really be one set of policies across three sets of environments (which ends up becoming 6 sets of policies, content definition files etc)?!

Fantasising a bit - I think ideally we'd configure MSAL to send the environment to the policy somehow, and then *at least* make that variable available in the policy files so that they could perhaps fetch the content definition files with a query parameter?

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.signin">
    <LoadUri>https://storage.com/adb2c/signin-{Culture:RFC5646}.html?env={environment}</LoadUri>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use DevOps and [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-devops).

You can then search and replace the variables that you need to change across environments.